# Dependency convergence error when using Firebase-admin and Springboot

Tags: java, spring-boot, notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-admin

I am using Springboot and Firebase-admin to send mobile notification:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.firebase</groupId>
    <artifactId>firebase-admin</artifactId>
    <version>8.1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

After adding Firebase-admin dependency I get dependency convergence error when trying to build the project:

```
[WARNING]
Dependency convergence error for com.google.http-client:qoogle-http-client- 
jackson2:1.25.0 paths to dependency are:

+-com.test.notification:notification-service:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
 +-com. google.firebase:firebase-admin:6.8.1
  +-com.google.api-client:google-api-client:1.25.0
   +-com.google.http-client:google-http-client-jackson2:1.25.0
and
+-com.test.notification:notification-service:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
 +-com.google.firebase:firebase-admin:6.8.1
  +-com.google.auth: google-auth-library-oauth2-http: 0.18.0
   +-com.google.http-client:google-http-client-jackson2:1.32.1
and
+-com.test.notification:notification-service:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
 +-com.google.firebase:firebase-admin:6.8.1
  +-com.google.cloud:google-cloud-storage:1.100.0
   +-com.google.cloud:google-cloud-core-http:1.91.3
     +-com.google.cloud: google-cloud-core:1.91.3
       +-com.google.http-client:google-http-client-jackson2:1.32.1
...

[Warning] Rule 0: org.apache.maven.plugins.enforcer.DependencyConvergence failed with message:
Failed while enforcing releasability. See above detailed error message
```